# Search for a specific string using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In a supposed Bank Database I made a 50x7 char array of pointers (50 users, 7 pieces of information [strings] for each user).

I have to ask for the user to input a username (5th column contains all 50 usernames) so the program finds it in that array and deletes all the information relevant to that user (replace all columns of that row with 0).

Whenever I type a username and press Enter for the program to search and "erase", it instantly crashes.

I'm a serious noob at programming, so keep it as simple as possible. (no auto functions) every variable and pointer is properly initiated.

below is the specific part that troubles me. Thank you for your time I've spent an entire day trying to get a hang of this.

```
char* users[50][7];
char deluser[50], delaction[50]; //Delete Existing User
int flagfinder, delmenu, flagresearch=0; //Delete Existing User

while (delmenu == 0) {
    flagfinder = 0;
    printf("Type the username of the customer you want to erase off of the database:\n");
    scanf("%s", deluser);

    for (x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        y = 1;
        while (flagresearch == 0 || y < 50) {
            if (deluser[y] != *(users[x][5] + y)) {
                flagresearch = 1;
            }
            y++;
        }
        if (flagresearch == 0) {
            printf("Are you sure you want to delete %s's info?(Yes/No)\n", deluser);
            scanf("%s", delaction);
            while (strcmp(delaction, "Yes") != 0 && strcmp(delaction, "No") != 0) {
                printf("Try again.Are you sure you want to delete %s's info?(Yes/No)\n", deluser);
            }
            if (strcmp(delaction, "Yes") == 0) {
                for (y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
                    *users[x][y] = 0;
                }
                printf("\n%s's data has been erased from the mainframe.\n\n");
                flagfinder = 1;
                delmenu = 1;
            } else
            if (strcmp(delaction, "No") == 0) {
            }
        }
    }
    if (flagfinder == 0) {
        printf("There is no %s in the database.\n", deluser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format this code, and don't use non-standard things like `system("cls")` since many of us don't have windows machine and then it's hard to test your code. If you don't post the declaration/definition of `deluser` it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take time to review the help on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, the code you have provided is incomplete. Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: @iharob system("cls") just "clears" the screen. added the declarations of the used variables/pointers.

Comment: @A.Raikos I know what it does it just doesn't work everywhere and since your are asking here maybe testing your code is something that many will do so avoid such non-standard tricks.

Comment: I don't even know what is considered non-standard. I didn't even know there was such a thing. I just started learning C and so far this program is running great with the exception of this small part I posted on which it crashes.

I'm asking here because I made a two-dimensional array full of pointers pointing at strings and I need to search that array. I didn't know pointers 6 hours ago give me a tiny break and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After reformatting your code, it becomes obvious that you are not compiling with the proper warning level.  The compiler would have spotted this bug:

```
if (flagfinder = 0) {
```

It is also unlikely that this line does what you expect:

```
while (flagresearch == 0, y < 50)
```

The code to compare the user name looks wrong:

```
    while (flagresearch == 0 || y < 50) {
        if (deluser[y] != *(users[x][5] + y)) {
            flagresearch = 1;
        }
        y++;
    }
```

This will always compare `50` bytes, including bytes that `fscanf` did not initialize. It can only work if the strings are pointed to by `users[x][5]` are exactly 49 bytes and a NUL byte.  I suspect you are reading beyond the end of an array, or possibly dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.  Are you sure all database strings are allocated?

You might use this instead:

```
    flagresearch = (users[x][5] == NULL) || strcmp(users[x][5], deluser);
```

Note that unless multiple users can have the same name, it would be more intuitive to use a single positive flag such as `flagfound` and break from the  `for` loop when you find a match.

Comment: my bad, those were written hastily. I corrected these. program still crashes before it executes the commands you mentioned.